# Show the klein group and <i> is not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

One part in particular that I'm stuck on (other than the whole thing, so seeing the solution will help) is why is  order 2? To me, it should be 4 as {1, i, -1, -i}.

Answer (score 1):

The order of $i$ is $4$, you are absolutely right.

On the other hand every element of the Klein four-group is of order $2$. Hence they cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

$<i>$ is cyclic $i, i^2=-1, i^3=-1(i)=-i, i^4=1$ but not is the Klein group which is $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$.